# Why does the J-test yield a $\chi^2$ distribution?

Tags: econometrics, f-statistic, chi-squared-distribution

My econometrics professor recently introduced us to the J-test. To perform the J-test, he gave us the following procedure:

1. Estimate $\mathbf{b}^{2SLS}$ and using this, define $\hat{U}_n$ residuals for all $n$ observations in the random sample.
2. Regress $\hat{U}_n$ on $\mathbf{W}_n$ (exogenous variables) and $\mathbf{Z}_n$ (instrumental variables).
3. Define null hypothesis as the instrumental variables are exogenous (not sure how to phrase this mathematically). Compute $J \equiv mF$ where $F$ is the F-statistic corresponding to this test.

$J$ is then the J-statistic.

## My Question

Why is $J\sim \chi^2_{m-k}$? I thought $F$ had an $F$ distribution, which itself is the ratio of two $\chi^2$ distributions. Why does multiplying the $F$-statistic by a constant suddenly change it into a completely different distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not multiplying by a constant that does it, it's just looking at the asymptotics as your number of observations goes to infinity! Wave your magical asymptotics wand and *poof*, the $F$ distribution becomes $\chi^2$.

The $F$ stat is a ratio of two normalized $\chi^2$ distributions:
$$ F_{d_1, d_2} = \frac{\chi^2_{d_1} / d_1}{\chi^2_{d_2} / d_2}$$
In the context of regression, $d_2$ for the classic $F$ stat is $n - k$ (the degrees of freedom of the residuals).

As $n$ goes to infinity, the degrees of freedom $d_2$ goes to infinity , and the $F$ distribution converges to a scaled $\chi^2$ distribution. Loose intuition: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\chi^2_n}{n} = 1$ and dividing by 1 doesn't do anything.

### Additional note:

A similar thing happens with t-distribution and the normal distribution. T-distribution with infinite degrees of freedom is a normal distribution. You'll sometimes see z-score instead of t-stats etc...

Comment: +1 Thanks for replying! Could you add an aside on how to mathematically state a null hypothesis that the instrumental variables are exogenous?

Comment: @StanShunpike that seems like an entirely different question. If you want a rigorous, sophisticated but clear treatment of the assumptions of IV, I'd recommend taking a look at Hayashi's *Econometrics*. More colloquial and practitioner oriented, I'd checkout *Mostly Harmless Econometrics*.

Comment: Separate question. Does this mean for the J-test to be applicable, you need an infinite number of data points in the random sample?

Comment: A related question would be, "How many observations do you need for the central limit theorem (CLT) to be applicable?" In a rigorous mathematical sense, the CLT is a statement about the limit as $n$ goes to infinity. But in most real world cases, the mean of IID random variables starts looking pretty damn close to the normal distribution for reasonable, finite samples... How many observations does it take? It depends...